# How to set up port forwarding on a NETGEAR ProSafe™ Gigabit 8 Port VPN Firewall FVS318N?

Tags: firewall, routing, port, port-forwarding, netgear

UPDATE:  Rule might be right, but app still isn't functional.  See more details after the screenshots.

I want to forward port 3000 to a machine in the local network (`192.168.1.106`).

So far I've created a service under Security>Services

[image]

I also created rules in the firewall in both outbound and inbound under Security>Firewall:

[image]

[image]

---

Edit: more screenshots

[image]

[image]

I've tested an online port scanner tool here: http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/
and it shows as "responding" on port 3000.  If I disable the app on my server and run the test it shows as "not responding".  This would indicate that the port is open and the rule is right, but the app still isn't functional.

It's a test rails app.

I'm going to get Wireshark running to help debug.

Any ideas on why the app isn't working is appreciated.

Comment: @marcgg as TheCleaner mentioned - if it's responding then your app. may not be configured properly.

Comment: @TheCleaner on the machine if I try to access localhost:3000 it does work. Isn't it possible that the response gets lost somehow. For instance if the router does answer okay but forwards it into the void?

Comment: The router isn't whats responding, the rule forwards the request to the server.  Disable the app/port 3000 on the server and what the "test" from that url fail as well.  ALSO, if any of those other rules above it going to those other internal IPs include port 3000 they will get hit first.  Make sure that isn't the case.

Comment: @Cole When I try to access http://192.168.1.106:3000/ it does work, so  it seems that the local app is fine. I might be missing something though

Comment: @TheCleaner okay I get it, good call! Now I shut down my local app and it says that it doesn't respond anymore. But the weird thing is that I don't see any access in my logs when the app was running.

Comment: That's a different question altogether :)  Your rule was just fine.  Best to delete this question entirely and ask a new one if necessary with details on the app on the server.  The firewall rule is right.

Comment: @TheCleaner I really don't get it. I've set up port forwarding countless time on very simpler interfaces, and once the message has been forwarded to my local machine it would just work fine. Isn't there something else I need to do other than setting this rule ?

Comment: Not on the firewall.  Responding is responding.  You can grab wireshark and prove the requests are coming in if you want.  You'll need to start debugging the app side itself if the client app isn't working.  But the networking seems ok based on the info provided.  WAIT...are you certain it ONLY listens on port 3000 for this app?  Maybe it uses more than just that port?

Comment: Are you trying to test it from behind the firewall?  A bunch of firewalls will not hairpin traffic?

Comment: @Doon there shouldn't be a firewall here, but I start to doubt that things are how they are supposed to be :)

Comment: If your jenkins app on port 8080 works that should prove that the firewall rule "test" is setup right as well as the online port scan tool verifying it is responding. :)

Comment: @TheCleaner jenkins is running on 8080 but I'm making all my tests on "test" that is running on a rails app running on port 3000 since I'm not 100% sure that jenkins would be responding correctly.

Comment: @marcgg what I mean is if you are on 192.168.1.x and you are trying to go to http://external.ip.addr:3000/ some NAT devices cannot hair pin the traffic so the nat might be working fine from oustside (As demonstrated by the your test, but not from inside. AKA hairpinnig since it the router/firewall/etc  is basically talking to itself.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this helps but I noticed that there is not a UDP service for "test".  You would have to add that to the inbound/outbound rules.

Comment: Why would one need UDP for a service that runs over TCP?